# Is there any way how to deactivate child process on Visual Studio Debug End

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I start another process  from my aplication:

```cs
private readonly ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = $@"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}\External\app.exe",
    Arguments = "",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
};
...
void Open()
{
    this.SensorCheckProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    this.SensorCheckProcess.StartInfo = this.startInfo;
    this.SensorCheckProcess.Start();
    this.ErrorReader = this.SensorCheckProcess.StandardError;
    this.OutputReader = this.SensorCheckProcess.StandardOutput;
    this.InputWriter = this.SensorCheckProcess.StandardInput;
}
```

I can stop process by writing `exit` into `this.InputWriter`. But I usualy stop my debugging by `SHIFT+F5`, and process `app.exe` stays open and I have to shut it manualy in Task Manager.
Is there any way, how to setup Aplication or Visual Studio to abort process automaticly.

Comment: What about `Process.Kill()`? ... edit: ok, so it's about stopping child process when parent process was killed  then: **you can't do automatically**

Comment: I can `Kill` the child process. But I need do it only on Exit from Debuging. And there is no event or method there.

Comment: AFAIK the only way is to find(Process.GetProcesses) and kill all processes previously started before new process start

Comment: If it is the debugging target that is the parent process you need to have the child processes detect their parent has gone, and they then end themselves. (The debugger terminates its target, so you cannot do something in that process.)

Comment: @Richard Unfortunately the child process is closed binery. I can't change code inside.

Comment: See if [this document](https://gist.github.com/jvshahid/6fb2f91fa7fb1db23599) can help you.